# Discord bot won't run startup sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I am making a discord bot and it won't run a sequence that I made that says when it joins a server, it should make a role, a category, and two channels in that category.

````
async def on_server_join(ctx):
  await ctx.guild.create_category('Friend')
  await ctx.guild.create_role(name="friend.admin", mentionable=True)
  category = ctx.guild.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name='Friend')
  await ctx.guild.create_text_channel('Chat-with-@Friend', category=category)
  guild = ctx.guild
  admin_role = ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin"
  overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: ctx.guild.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        guild.me: ctx.guild.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        admin_role: ctx.guild.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
  await guild.create_text_channel('secret', overwrites=overwrites, category=category)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the event is `on_guild_join(guild)`. Try this out:

```py
@bot.event # or client.event based on your code
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    await guild.create_category('Friend')
    # rest of your code
```

So, instead of passing in `ctx`, the event takes in `guild`, and you can create channels, roles, categories, etc., with `guild.create` instead of `ctx.guild.create`.

Comment: but `guild` doesn't operate as an object. It has to be an attribute of `ctx`. Otherwise it errs out

Comment: @James no not really, you don't need `ctx` to get access of `guild` and its attributes. Try out my code, and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To control what happens when your bot joins a server, you will need to use the `on_guild_join` event. You are trying to use `on_server_join` with a ctx parameter,
`ctx` is generally used as the context for commands.

```
@bot.command()
async def on_guild_join(guild):  #guild is a discord.Guild
    await guild.create_channel('Friend')
    # make sure you have permissions
```

### References:

- [on_guild_join](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild_join#discord.on_guild_join)
- [bot events](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20event#discord.ext.commands.Bot.event)
- [guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.abc.GuildChannel.guild)